# How to display only those nodes that current user has commented

Tags: views

On my D7 site I am trying to enable users to view the nodes where they have submitted their comments. I have tried adding 'Comments of the node' relationship, then added 'Comment: Author' and 'Comment: Author uid' contextual filters. Then set up filter criteria 'Comment: Author' to be equal/not equal to  [current-user:name] and [current-user:uid]. It didn't help.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: Hi, I use Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me without a problem. I'm not sure where my method differs from yours:

- Relationship: Comments of the node
- Contextual filter:

  - Author uid using comments relationship
  - Provide default value: "User ID from logged in user"
- Use aggregation: Yes (to avoid duplicate nodes)

That's all, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, it really works with default value in contextual filter. But what I needed was to create an exposed filter where current user would choose whether he wants to see all nodes, or only those he commented (or did not). I tried adding filter criteria 'Comment: Author uid' and setting up grouped filter using [current-user:uid] token. This didn't work.

Comment: Aah. Well that is a totally different question than the one had asked. 

I would probably just create 2 views for that, one with the filter, and one without. Rig it up with some javascript.